# How to do feature extraction for list of words?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I'm using Apache Spark ML (through the Java API) to analyse some free text.  I would like to construct a pipeline which extracts a feature which indicates whether any of preconfigured list of terms are present.

`CountVectorizer` seems to do almost what I'm after, but I would like to specify a vocabulary up front.  So far I've got:

```
    final Tokenizer tok = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("text").setOutputCol(
            "tokens");
    final StopWordsRemover swr = new StopWordsRemover().setInputCol(
            "tokens").setOutputCol("cleansed_tokens");
    final CountVectorizer cv = new CountVectorizer()
    .setInputCol("cleansed_tokens").setOutputCol("vector");
    final Pipeline pl = new Pipeline().setStages(new PipelineStage[] { tok,
            swr, cv });
```

Is there a way to do this in Spark ML?  Do I need to write my own `Transformer`?

Comment: I think that `StopWordsRemover` might show you how to create a `Transformer` that would be an extension of `CountVectorizer`. Can you show the input and output datasets to know exactly what you want to achieve?